# SwiftでUIView<FooProtocol, BarProtocol>相当の宣言て出来ますか？

Tags: swift, objective-c

Objective-Cでは以下のように、複数のプロトコルを実装した具体的な型で変数宣言やプロパティ定義など出来ますが、

```
UIView<FooProtocol, BarProtocol>* myView = ...
```

Swiftでは同様の書き方ありませんか？

Comment: ちょっと気になったので教えてください。Swift で `UIView<FooProtocol, BarProtocol>* myView = ...` のようにしたい場面てありますか？型推論あるしいらないかな、と思うのですが。

Comment: そういうフィールドを持ちたい時に、必要になりました。
ローカル変数では`let myView = ...`でOKですね。

Comment: @ShintaroAbe
あと、メソッドの戻り値の型などの指定でも必要になったりします。
上の`let myView = ...`の例でも、`let myView = foo.barMethod()`などの時、`barMethod`の戻り値を`UIView<FooProtocol, BarProtocol>*`相当の書き方が出来ないとダメなので、型推論が効く場合でも結局表題の表現力は必要になってくると思っています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。こういう時ってUIViewのprotocolがあると良いんでしょうかね？

    protocol FooBarView: UIViewProtocol,FooProtocol,BarProtocol {}
    class A: FooBarView {
        ...
    }
    class B: FooBarView {
        ...
    }
    func fooBarView() -> FooBarView {
       return A()
    }
    let a = fooBarView()

ただ、UIViewのメソッドを全部実装するのは面倒なので、結局サブクラスの方が良いのかな、と思いました。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

直接Objective-Cと同じことはできませんが、型拡張で同じ事はできると思います。型Tがprotocolに適合していればそれはグローバルな状態だとおもうので、これでいいんじゃないでしょうか。

```
protocol FooProtocol {
    var foo: String { get }
}
protocol BarProtocol {
    var bar: String { get }
}

extension UIView: FooProtocol, BarProtocol {
    var foo: String { return "foo" }
    var bar: String { return "bar" }
}

let a = UIView()
a.foo // "foo"
a.bar // "bar"
```

Comment: ありがとうございます、継承して新しい型を作る似た方法もありますが(もう1つの回答に記載)、やはりそのどちらかですね。

Answer (score 3):

似てますが、以下の方法もありますね。

```
protocol FooProtocol {
    var foo: String { get }
}
protocol BarProtocol {
    var bar: String { get }
}

class CompositeProtocolUIView: UIView, FooProtocol, BarProtocol {
    var foo: String { return "foo" }
    var bar: String { return "bar" }
}

let a = CompositeDelegateUIView()
a.foo // "foo"
a.bar // "bar"
```

Answer (score 2):

Genericsを使うことで具体的かつ必要最低限の制約で書くことができます。

```
class MyClass <T:UIView where T:FooProtocol, T:BarProtocol> {
    var fbView:T?
}
```

ちなみに

```
class FooBarButton : UIButton, FooProtocol, BarProtocol {}
```

型を決め打ちするやり方だと今回は UIButton,Foo,Bar → UIView,Foo,Bar のキャストをさせてもらえず渡すことができない一方、Genericsなら上のようなクラスもプロパティに代入できます。